# Ubuntu Servers 'loose' DNS and need to run netplay apply

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, netplan

I've got a bunch of ubuntu 18,20 servers (web/app) and their /etc/netplan/conf.yaml has the nameservers pointing to our 2 ubuntu bind/dns servers.

Randomly, and often, I need to run  `netplay apply` on the app servers because they stop talking to the DNS server.

I tail /var/log/syslog and don't see any issue reported in the log.
Where should I be looking?

Thanks!

Example conf file, 192.168.10.6/7 are my DNS servers, 10.1 is our router

```
/etc/netplan$ cat 0-conf.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.10.129/24
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.10.6
        - 192.168.10.7
        - 192.168.10.1
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2
```

Comment: How do you know that they stop talking to the DNS servers? What happens when you run `ping DOMAIN-NAME` or `dig DOMAIN-NAME`? I think that Ubuntu 18 deploys `systemd-resolved` by default and puts 127.0.0.53 in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If that is your configuration, you need to troubleshoot `systemd-resolved`.

Comment: if I ping, I get 'Name or service not known'

Comment: Does your system use `systemd-resolved`? If so, start at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328131/how-to-troubleshoot-dns-with-systemd-resolved.